# Change only action bar color (no tabs color) - appCompat v 21

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am using appCompat v21 and I want to change color of actionbar to black while actionbar tabs should be white. Setting colorPrimary changes colors of both actionbar and tabs. I have tried setting theme to light and then using actionBarStyle with black background but this apparently doesnt work in appcompat v21.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Thanks in forward

Comment: You can call `getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(YOUR_COLOR)));`

Comment: hmm I put this in my onCreate method but nothing happened and the color is the same (tried it also in onCreateOptionsMenu)

Comment: Action bar tabs were deprecated in Android 5.0. You may wish to consider using another tab solution (e.g., `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator).